# Reversing a "boolean" in C

Tags: c

Is it possible to do something like this in C:

```
in_char = 0;
in_char = not in_char; // get it to 1?
```

Currently I'm doing the following, but I feel like it's not the best approach:

```
    if (c == '\'') {
        if (in_char == 0) {
            in_char = 1
        } else if (in_char == 1) {
            in_char = 0
        }
    }
```

What would be a 'cleaner' way to do the above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the negation operator:

```
in_char = !in_char;
```

Alternatively, if you include `<iso646.h>`, your suggested code will work literally:

```
#include <iso646.h>
...
in_char = not in_char;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `!` operator to negate the value of a boolean.

Don't check for `== 1` if you only care whether the result is true or not, you can just use the value in the `if`.

You can do this:

```
if (in_char) {
    do something
} else {
    do another thing
}
```

If you don't care about the `true` case, you can directly negate the check:

```
if (!in_char) {
    do another thing
}
```